# Java - Serialize Abstract Class using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, objectmapper

I have two Java classes that I want to serialize to Json.

```
@JsonRootName(value = "ani")
public abstract class Animal {

private final String eat;

public Animal(String eat) {
   this.eat = eat;
}

}

public class Car extends Dog {

private final String eat;
private final String bark;

public Dog(String, eat, String bark) {
super(eat);
this.bark = bark;
}

}
```

Main.Java

```
Animal ani = new Dog("food", "oof");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
String result = mapper.writeValueAsString();
```

But this was the result:

```
{"ani": {"eat":"food",
  "bark":"oof"}
```

Instead of:

```
{"ani": {"eat":"food",
  "dog": {"bark":"oof"}}
```

How can I include the "Dog" object in the JSON?